# How can I maintain scroll position in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to save the scroll position in a fragment. Flow->

1. Fragment A - scrolled to some position
2. Fragment B
3. Come back to Fragment A to the same position and not create everything from the top.

My attempts

**Attempt 1**

```
private var index: Int = -1
private var top = -1
private var lastFirstVisiblePosition : Int? = null
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    index = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val v: View = homeRecyclerView!!.getChildAt(0)
    top = v.top - homeRecyclerView!!.paddingTop

    val preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    preferences.edit()
        .putInt("position", index)
        .putInt("offset", top)
        .apply();

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val preferences =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    index = preferences.getInt("position",0)
    top = preferences.getInt("offset",0)

    if(this.index != -1)
    {
        (homeRecyclerView!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager)
            .scrollToPositionWithOffset(index,top)
    }
}
```

Outcome: Doesn't scroll. Code reaches the line `(homeRecyclerView!!.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(index,top)` but doesn't scroll

**Attempt 2**

```
    private val BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT = "classname.recycler.layout"

override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        val savedRecyclerLayoutState: Parcelable? =
            savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT)
        homeRecyclerView!!.layoutManager!!.onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState)
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putParcelable(BUNDLE_RECYCLER_LAYOUT, homeRecyclerView!!.layoutManager!!.onSaveInstanceState());
}
```

Outcome: No error but doesn't scroll

**Attempt 3**

```
    override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    state = linearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()
}
```

I know something about **Parcelable** but I don't know how to implement it

My HomeFragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {



private var homePostAdapter: HomePostAdapter? = null
private var postList: MutableList<HomePostModel>? = null
val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
var homeRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

private var userFollowingList: MutableList<HomePostModel>? = null
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)



    homeRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view_home)

    linearLayoutManager.reverseLayout = true
    linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true

    homeRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    postList = ArrayList()
    homePostAdapter =
        context?.let { HomePostAdapter(it, postList as ArrayList<HomePostModel>, true) }
    homeRecyclerView!!.adapter = homePostAdapter


    homeRecyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)

    homeRecyclerView!!.setItemViewCacheSize(20)

    return view


}
```

On returning to this fragment, I want to get the scroll position the user was on. Right now, it loads from the top. My attempts have no error hence I don't understand what's wrong. Thank you for the help.

**UPDATE**

The issue was that I had not given a small delay using `Holder().postDelayed`. It's working fine now.

However, could someone kindly tell me the correct way to retrieve the **exact** position of the scroll? Right now my attempt 1 is working but the scroll is *jumpy* and not exact.

**UPDATE 2**

I found the `dy` position and using it scroll to last state. See answer. If anyone has a better approach, kindly let me know.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states. RecyclerView should save its state by itself, you only need to set an ID on it. What I think is happening is that you're setting the adapter without having set the content first. There a relatively new solution to this [described here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334), but the most common solution is to set your adapter after your data.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So the adapter has to be set after I add the data ?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: Thank you. I have the id of the recyclerview ( home_rec_view). If you could kindly tell me how to use it to save scroll position, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the onCreateView I have found the `dy` and based on that I am finding the scroll position. Since `dy` is only available in the `smoothScroll`, I use that on `onResume` to get back to the position.

Inside the fragment/Activity:

```
homeRecyclerView!!.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            scrolled += dy

            val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            preferences.edit()
                .putInt("position", scrolled)
                .apply()

        }
    })
```

OnResume:

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    val index = preferences.getInt("position", 0)

        homeRecyclerView!!.smoothScrollBy(0, index)
    }, 50)

}
```